# How can I investigate the source of an Access Violation that occurs on launching the app?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, access-violation

I´m new to C++ programing. I am compiling a Windows Application which compiles ok with just a few warnings, but when I launch it, it doesn´t even seem to start and returns an Access Violation 3 seconds into the run. When I try to debug it doesn´t even seem to get into the code, so I don´t know where to start looking for the problem.

Here is the info I have been able to retrieve from the debugger:

```
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Build succeeded
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: C:\Documents and Settings\Christian Ekiza\Mis documentos\My Dropbox\Private Files\coding\juego_pruebas_01\juego_pruebas_01\
Adding source dir: C:\Documents and Settings\Christian Ekiza\Mis documentos\My Dropbox\Private Files\coding\juego_pruebas_01\juego_pruebas_01\
Adding file: bin\Debug\juego_pruebas_01.exe
Starting debugger: 
done
Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb 6.8
Child process PID: 3328
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In ?? () ()
```

and this is from the Call Stack

```
#0 00000000 0x000154e4 in ??() (??:??)
#1 00409198 __cmshared_create_or_grab() (../../../../gcc-4.4.1/libgcc/../gcc/config/i386/cygming-shared-data.c:140)
#2 00000000 0x0040131b in __gcc_register_frame() (??:??)
#3 00000000 0x0040a09b in register_frame_ctor() (??:??)
#4 00000000 0x00408f42 in __do_global_ctors() (??:??)
#5 00000000 0x00401095 in __mingw_CRTStartup() (??:??)
#6 00000000 0x00401148 in mainCRTStartup() (??:??)
```

And the CPU Registers end with a

```
'gs' register with a hex value '0x0'
```

I don't really know where to start looking for the problem. Anyone can help me out or point me in the right direction?

Note: I am using Code::Blocks

Comment: Reduce the problem to a minimal example program. If that process doesn't tell you what the problem is, post the complete minimal example program code. As well as build commands etc. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I was using 3 cpp+h files, on for bitmaps, one for sprites and one for an engine. The 3 files worked fine in an example program, but mine was crashing. I reduced the example program down to just paint a BMP file on screen and verified that it still worked. Then I just swapped the BMP file with one of my application. It crashed. After looking for the difference between the bitmaps, it appears that mine was not in the correct format, because it crashed. After some try and errors, I managed to have it not to crash, but the image was all black. Then I found that the BMP had to include a palette.

Comment: Now the picture can be loaded correctly. Next, I'll try to see that all pictures are in the correct format. And start adding each piece at a time.

Answer (score 1):

As you say it is a Windows application. Then, any issues with startup, I have found [ADPlus](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350) very useful.

EDIT 2:

You may also check [User Mode Process Dumper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=E089CA41-6A87-40C8-BF69-28AC08570B7E&displaylang=en) if ADPlus does not apply

Comment: Wouldn´t this be my case? When should you not use ADPlus?
Do not use ADPlus in the following situations:
If you must troubleshoot a program or process that quits unexpectedly during startup. You can only use ADPlus for processes that start successfully. To troubleshoot processes that quit unexpectedly during startup, User Mode Process Dump may be a better solution. For more information about User Mode Process Dump, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
253066  ... Should I try this "User Mode Process Dump"?

Comment: Oops!. Your comment and my REEDIT crossed each other. Yes, that is true. You will have to give it a try since it is giving 'access violation' rather than unexpected termination. Unexpected termination is different from access violation.

Comment: You can use process dumper for ANY process exit.

Comment: I used the User Mode Process Dump and opened it with WinDbg and this is the info that it has in it: Loading unloaded module list
.
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(5f8.cc): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
eax=0023feb7 ebx=00000004 ecx=00000000 edx=0023fe97 esi=00411749 edi=0023fee0
eip=0001747c esp=0023fe1c ebp=0023fef8 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010202
0001747c ??              ???

Comment: If you have a proper debug build with proper symbols you can use Windbg stack trace commands (http://windbg.info/download/doc/pdf/WinDbg_cmds.pdf) to get the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

See, if you have some global instance(s) of class with constructor - if error is raised in constructor and class is declared globally (bad thing to do btw) - you'll get sigsegv even before main().
If you have such classes - try to refactor your code to have them inside main (or other function) - it will be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following free MS tools - both are great for debugging this kind of problem.

- Application Verifier http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=c4a25ab9-649d-4a1b-b4a7-c9d8b095df18&displaylang=en
- Gflags from Debugging Tools for Windows http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like one of your DLL dependencies can't be loaded or instantiated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you you compile with debug mode (`-g`) enabled?

Also seriously consider actually fixing the warnings. Most of the time they are actual problems in the code that should be resolved.

You should also try to see if this happens with a nearly empty main (comment out most/all of your code in `main`).